# Conversion from mysql to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm continue to rewrite my codes from `mysql_*` to `PDO` and learn it while I do this but I'm a little stuck with this one. Here I got answer empty when I run it `[][][][]`. This is old code

```
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$objDB = mysql_select_db("mytable");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM table";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
$intNumField = mysql_num_fields($objQuery);
$resultArray = array();
while($obResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
{
    $arrCol = array();
    for($i=0;$i<$intNumField;$i++)
    {
        $arrCol[mysql_field_name($objQuery,$i)] = $obResult[$i];
    }
    array_push($resultArray,$arrCol);
}

mysql_close($objConnect);
echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

And this is what I trying

```
include 'database.php';
$pdo = Database::connect();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM table";
$resultArray = array(); 
foreach($pdo->query($strSQL) as $res)
{
    $arrCol = array();
    for($i=0;$i<$strSQL;$i++)
    {
        $arrCol[mysql_field_name($res,$i)] = $strSQL[$i];
    }
    array_push($resultArray,$arrCol);
}   
echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `mysql_field_name` doesn't mix with PDO API that you're currently using.

Just write it using PDO all through out. Just [`fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) it and set the additional flag `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`. It'll return it with the column names / without numeric indices.

```
include 'database.php';
$pdo = Database::connect();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$strSQL = 'SELECT * FROM table';

$resultArray = array(); 
$res = $pdo->query($strSQL);
while($row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $resultArray[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

Additional Info:

You can also omit that loop by using [`->fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) using the same flag:

```
$resultArray = $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: So the loop is for reimplementing ->fetchAll then ?

Comment: @mario yeah, i haven't thought of that. `->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` is way better.

Comment: What exactly is difference between then since they return same result?

Comment: @JasonPaddle check out the link, on the `return value` section. its eloquently stated there.

Comment: With `fetchAll()` doesn't display anything but with `fetch()` is displayed.

Comment: @JasonPaddle just make sure you use it after the query has been made

Comment: Yes, like this, `while($row = $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {` and is empty.

Comment: @JasonPaddle no, remove the `while` loop, in the end, it'll be just a one liner. here: http://pastebin.com/qRZePvnD

Answer (score 2):

```
$pdo = Database::connect();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
echo json_encode(
    $pdo->query(
        'SELECT * FROM soFoo'
    )->fetchAll()
);
```

see http://docs.php.net/pdostatement.fetchall